Constructing series representations for multivariate functions using complex numbers
I was using Wolfram to get a decent plot of $f(x,y)=\frac {x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ and I saw that it had generated several series representations of the function. One such was as follows, which I'll call (1):
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 12 x^n(-1)(((-iy)^n+(iy)^n)y^{1-2n})$$
Here is another, which I'll call (2):
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 12 y^ni(((-ix)^n+(ix)^n)x^{1-2n})$$
It's pretty clear that (1) and (2) are similar. However, there was the third that Wolfram spat out (3):
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 12 (-1+y)^n(-1)(i(x^2(\frac{(-1-ix)^{-n}}{-i+x}-\frac{(-1+ix)^{-n}}{i+x})))$$
How would one arrive at a series expansion for a multivariate function such as $f(x,y)$? What makes (1) and (2) similar, and why is (3) of a different form? Moreover, how would complex numbers get involved? My only experience with series representations of functions has been with Taylor and Fourier series, so I'm still relatively early on in my exploration of this specific topic.
Edit: fixed parentheses on (3).
